# AngularJS: Update view content from layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, view

You can see what I am trying to do in the following image.

[image]

Mainly I have two sections on the page. The Header section contains a common menu and a search textbox.

When the user clicks on the menu, for instance Movies, the Movies.html view will be loaded in the section marked with ng-view.

Each view has his own controller defined as following:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/", { templateUrl: "app/albums.html", controller: "albumController" })
    .when("/games", { templateUrl: "app/games.html", controller: "gamesController" })...etc
```

So far so good. The idea is that when the user searches something on the textbox the current view will be updated.

I could have a commonController wrapping the searchTextbox HTML but...how can I update the $scope of the current loaded view from this controller?

What is the best approach to achieve that?

Thanks all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) for that.

Your **commonController** will notify this service:

```
commonController.$inject = ['NotifyViewFactory'];
function commonController(NotifyViewFactory){
  var vm = this;
  vm.inputModel = '';

  this.notifyService = function(){
    NotifyViewFactory.setValue(vm.inputModel); 
  };

  //may be in your example better to listen when route changed:
  //and then use service
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(scope, next, current){
    NotifyViewFactory.setValue(vm.inputModel);
  });
}
```

And factory will look like this:

```
NotifyViewFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
function NotifyViewFactory($rootScope){
  return {
    setValue: setValue
  };

  function setValue(data){
    //do something with data if necessary
    $rootScope.$emit('inputUpdated', data);
  }
}
```

And view controller:

```
viewController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];
function viewController($rootScope, $scope){
  $rootScope.$on('inputUpdated',function(event, data){
    $scope.someValue = data.someValue;
  });
}
```

So, that data from **commonController** can be passed to **viewController** without any changes, or if you need some change - you can do that in *setValue* method of **NotifyViewFactory** (before [$rootScope.$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) call).

Comment: I still don't know if it is the best approach but the pub/sub pattern with $emit/$on worked for me. Thank you very much Vadim.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a $scope variable that is accessible across controllers.

In your header controller define:

'$scope.global = {};'

Then assign the search value to that object, such as:

'$scope.global.searchValue = "Ready Player One"'

You'll then be ale to access that variable in your other controllers without having to go through all the complexity of using a service.

Comment: Accordingly to [Angular wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) about scopes and angular controller [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) - it's not a good practice. And in this example header controller is not an ancestor of view controller.

Comment: I agree a service is a better practice, but using scope is a simple solution. The controllers don't have to have a ancestral relationship to share scope in this context.